# Unreal Engine 4.27.2 from source - Package failed, Exit Code 3

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript, glue42

I'm getting this error when trying to package the Dedicated Server for shipping, I'm using github version. UE4.27.2

```
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: begin: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: Fatal error: [File:D:/UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release/Engine/Source/Editor/UnrealEd/Private/Commandlets/MakeBinaryConfigCommandlet.cpp] [Line: 102]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: Failed to create Config.bin file
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffccb96039c KERNELBASE.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc66ad9de6 UE4Editor-Core.dll!ReportAssert() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsPlatformCrashContext.cpp:1644]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc66addc88 UE4Editor-Core.dll!FWindowsErrorOutputDevice::Serialize() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsErrorOutputDevice.cpp:78]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc667efd10 UE4Editor-Core.dll!FOutputDevice::LogfImpl() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Misc\OutputDevice.cpp:61]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc5faf033b UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll!UMakeBinaryConfigCommandlet::Main() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Editor\UnrealEd\Private\Commandlets\MakeBinaryConfigCommandlet.cpp:102]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff684cfa17b UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!FEngineLoop::PreInitPostStartupScreen() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\LaunchEngineLoop.cpp:3434]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff684cf130d UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!GuardedMain() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Launch.cpp:132]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff684cf169a UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!GuardedMainWrapper() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:137]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff684cf4671 UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!LaunchWindowsStartup() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:273]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff684d05b74 UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!WinMain() [D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Private\Windows\LaunchWindows.cpp:320]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff684d07ac6 UE4Editor-Cmd.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288]
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffccce4244d KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffcce4cdfb8 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)):   LogWindows: Error: end: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)): Took 18,4770042s to run UE4Editor-Cmd.exe, ExitCode=3
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)): Editor terminated with exit code 3 while running MakeBinaryConfig for C:\Program Files\Epic Games\MyProject\MyProject.uproject; see log D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\MakeBinaryConfig-2022.12.08-20.16.40.txt
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Empacotamento (Windows (64-bit)): BUILD FAILED
```

I have already recompiled the engine resource: AutomationTool, recompiled the engine, and cleaned the project's binaries and recompiled it, but the error persists. Help.

Comment: What does the log say? `see log D:\UnrealEngine-4.27.2-release\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\MakeBinaryConfig-2022.12.08-20.16.40.txt`

Comment: This file basically says the same thing, I pressed Ctrl F and searched for "Error" and "LogError" and it starts from the log I posted above. The link to the full log file:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGSZh_vu0GZw7iwDQiYg9h0GrOqDtraMDYDaRJRHDBU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Good job finding the cause. I would also check those init warnings. This, if not used properly, can be an unending pool of garbage memory that can lead to crashes long-term, not to mention memory leaks or corrupt data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by disabling option: “Make Binary Config” in packaging options.